# How to resolve @Path conflict in jax-rs

Tags: jax-rs

Consider we have small web application with following routes:
"/" - return main page
"/post/add/" - return new post page

we write two following controllers to handle this routes:

```
@Path("/")
public class HomeController {
    @GET
    @Produces(HTML)
    public String home() {
        return render(new Page(HOME_PAGE_TEMPLATE));
    }
}
```

and

```
@Path("/post")
public class PostController {

    @GET
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces(HTML)
    public String add() {
        return render(new Page(ADD_USER_PAGE_TEMPLATE));
    }
}
```

the problem is "HomeController" now handle **all** requests. How to force it to handle **only** "/" route?

**UPD:**
The solution is use @Path("") annotation.

Comment: You can answer the question yourself and mark it as answered after some time. Please do so, so that other people with the same problem can easily find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is use @Path("") annotation